# htaccess - how to get only domain name and one variable inside url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, litespeed

my remote server is `LiteSpeed` - not `Appache`
not sure is it the same regarding `htaccess` code

original url - `example.com/index.php?c=kb`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

plus - `<base href="/">`

result - `example.com/home/kb` - works fine

now I want to remove `home` - to get - `example.com/kb`

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

the page is there but `css` and `js` are missing
seems problem is with `<base href="/">`
any help?

Comment: What URL do you want to see in browser and what it should become internally on server?

Comment: @anubhava - to see - `example.com/kb`. On server - `example.com/index.php?c=kb`

Comment: then try last line as: `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L]`

Comment: @anubhava - it works, thanks a lot. Will you place the answer? How can I learn this code, what language is this, give me any reference page, pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to see - `example.com/kb`. On server - `example.com/index.php?c=kb`

You may try this code for above scheme:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**References:**

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for sharing sir cheers.